# Example of a Regular Monic which is not Split

Tags: category-theory

I am looking for a nontrivial category such that its regular monics are not the same as its split monics.

The necessary definitions are found [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monomorphism).

A necessary requirement is that our category is not a (Epi, RegMonic)-factorization system, ie each arrow has an orthogonal epic/regular monic factorization.

Moreover, I am aware of trivial cases such as the category consisting of 3 objects and 4 non-identity arrows, $\{f\colon X\to Y,g\colon Y\to Z,h\colon Y\to Z,k=gf=hf\colon X\to Z\}$.

Comment: The nlab page specifies that any abelian category have all monomorphism regular. But there exists abelian categories where some short sequences do not split, so there must be non split monics.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$ is regular monic but non-split in $\mathbf{Ab}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In $\mathbf{Set}$ the unique function:

$\emptyset \rightarrow \{\emptyset\}$

is a regualr monomorphism, which is not split. More generally, in any elementary topos for every object $X$ the unique (necessary regular mono) morphism:

$$0 \rightarrow X$$

is non-split unless $X = 0$.

Comment: This is a good observation, but not really what I was after. Zhen Lin above comment was more along the lines. But thanks!